# google.maps.Geocoder.geocode() geometry.location lat/lng property names change frequently

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have an application, and I'm using the Google Javascript Geocoding API to fetch lat/lng for an address.

The code goes something like

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': query }, function(results, status) {
    addresses = {};
    $.each(results, function(index, value){
        addresses[index] = {"lat":value.geometry.location.$a,"lng":value.geometry.location.ab}
    })
});
```

All is fine and dandy, but the thing is that the property names of the location object periodically change. Each time they change, my site breaks.

Twice I've had to change my code to accommodate the weird lat/lng property name changes in google's geolocation api. Originally it was Xa, Ya, then I had to change to Ya, Za, and now its $a, ab. I don't see any user friendly logic behind these changes.

Does anyone know why these property names change, and/or what strategy can I use to obtain the lat/lng while avoiding the problems caused by these property name changes?

Comment: Ah, I just found the answer in a comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807141/retrieving-lat-long-of-location-using-google-maps-geocoder: "Google map's geocoder sometimes returns the lat and lng values as Pa and QA, other times it's Sa and Ta... the only guaranteed way is to use geometry.location.lat() and geometry.location.lng()"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Places API why does it returns Lat and Lon under a different variable each time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505928/google-places-api-why-does-it-returns-lat-and-lon-under-a-different-variable-eac)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the documented [properties](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder), they will not change

geometry.location is a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object, the documented methods are:

```
lat()   number  Returns the latitude in degrees.
lng()   number  Returns the longitude in degrees.
```