# Google maps autocomplete api v3 suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

So I was surprises to find after changing no code at all that the Google Maps auto-complete API suddenly stopped working. I logged out the results to see what was happening.

I had previously been getting a lat lng from an auto-completed address as follows:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(from_autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.d, from_autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.e);
```

the d and e being the lat and lng coords. I found the error to be that the response from the autocomplete object (autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location) is now:

```
k: 53.002668, A: -2.179403999999977
```

Why would the d and e suddenly change to a K and A? It had been working for weeks and then this changed without notice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google.maps.Geocoder.geocode() geometry.location lat/lng property names change frequently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499111/google-maps-geocoder-geocode-geometry-location-lat-lng-property-names-change-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used properties of internal object structure which can change any time.

`geometry` is `google.maps.places.PlaceGeometry` type with property `location` which is a `google.maps.LatLng` class. You can get latitude and longitude using officially supported `lat()` and `lng()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problem. Google maps and autocomplete suddenly not working then i follow these steps

-make "YOUR_API_KEY" from google developer console (https://console.developers.google.com)
then **enable following things(with Enable button) for current project in developer console**

Google Maps JavaScript API
**Google Places API Web Service Google**
Maps Geocoding API
Google Maps Geolocation API
(these are important features you can also enable other features if you want)

after that my problem solved