# Google Maps API Stopped Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

My website has been working fine up until the last couple of days.

The basic idea is that it gets your location and puts a marker on the map in your location (works fine) then adds a marker for up to 20 local spots of interest however these markers have stopped showing up. I haven't changed the code at all and I get results back for every part of the code, it seems to fail on the add marker function.

I don't receive any errors of any kind but I have noticed a random XHR call in the dev tools that I've never seen before and it references `QuotaService.RecordEvent` and it responds with `_xdc_._fqk4xg && _xdc_._fqk4xg( [0,null,1] )`.

I've tried searching everywhere for any information regarding this `QuotaService.RecordEvent` but nothing seems relevant to my issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google map api only permits some number of request per day. Maybe you have exausted them?

Comment: Which version of API do you use? Release, experimental?

Comment: I'm using release version and I haven't exceeded the quota, I checked in the API Console and my requests are nowhere near the limit.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I have been using variables that are not meant to be referenced i.e `geometry.location.d` and `geometry.location.e` which recently changed to `.a` and `.k`

See here: [Google maps autocomplete api v3 suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374559/google-maps-autocomplete-api-v3-suddenly-stopped-working)