# Google map is having some difficulty on loading?

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="my javascript browser key for website"&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

This is the command line what i am giving to load the Google map.
And this is the error it is showing

Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.
Please help me to solve this problem 
I am new to the codeigniter please help

Comment: What does your initAutocomplete function look like?

Comment: So what error message you can see in browser console?

Comment: Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.
This is the error in my rowser sonsole

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160006/google-maps-error-oops-something-went-wrong-this-page-didnt-load-google-maps) if it can help you.

Comment: If you use the correct Browser API key, check if you enabled Maps JavaScript API and Places API web service in your project. If everything is OK dive into JavaScript console and post what error message you can see there.

Comment: thanks for your attention ..
I have solved the issue.
I was getting error in creating api key.