# My site doesn't load Google Maps correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a website containing a simple google map. when I open the page everything is fine but suddenly map will be gone and the following message appear.

Oops! Something went wrong.

This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details

However, in my chrome and Firefox it works correctly but in other browsers and other chrome (maybe older version) in other computers, it doesn't work properly.

I would really appreciate if you could help me

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Maps error: Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38160006/1694185)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. this is because google just updated the API, so from now we have to get a API key

[Check this link to get a key from google map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

just create the API key and replace that key with YOUR_API_KEY in your js.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have a key. in my browser it is fine but in other it is not.