# Google map geocode api returns incorrect lat/lng key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3

The following code is almost straight out of a google sample code but I'm experiencing a strange issue. results[0].geometry.location has the keys "k" and "D" instead of "lat" and "lng".

Any idea why this might be happening?

```
    mapui.geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results[0]);
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location['lat'];
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location['lng'];
        }
    })
```

[image: notice the keys in locations]

Comment: possible duplicate of [google.maps.Geocoder.geocode() geometry.location lat/lng property names change frequently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499111/google-maps-geocoder-geocode-geometry-location-lat-lng-property-names-change-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `lat()` and `lng()` functions. The `geometry.location` is a `LatLng` class.

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Look in `__proto__` in your javascript console and you will find the available methods.