# Google Maps: Getting coordinates

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using **AngularJS** and **Google Maps API** I'm getting the coordinates from an address using this code:

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {

                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.A || results[0].geometry.location.G || results[0].geometry.location.H;
                    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.F || results[0].geometry.location.K || results[0].geometry.location.L;

                   //Something to do
            });
```

When I started the project I write only this:

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.A 
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.F;
```

In the pass of time, the Google Maps API changed the name of the variables to location.G and location.K and I needed to re-edit the code for this:

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.A || results[0].geometry.location.G;
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.F || results[0].geometry.location.K;
```

Now, the Google Maps API changed again the name of the variables to location.H and location.L...

*New code:*

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.A || results[0].geometry.location.G || results[0].geometry.location.H;
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.F || results[0].geometry.location.K || results[0].geometry.location.L;
```

**I don't want to edit more my code, I want my code stable... Is there any way to get the coordinates more stable?**

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a repeat of this question:

[google.maps.Geocoder.geocode() geometry.location lat/lng property names change frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499111/google-maps-geocoder-geocode-geometry-location-lat-lng-property-names-change-f)

The answer is:

> "Use the documented properties, they will not change. `geometry.location` is a `google.maps.LatLng` object, the documented methods are:
>   `lat()`   number  Returns the latitude in degrees.
>   `lng()`   number  Returns the longitude in degrees."