# Google Places API why does it returns Lat and Lon under a different variable each time?

Tags: javascript

This is driving me nuts, for some reason the API used to return the Lat and Lon like this:
(I think it was like this):

`place.geometry.location.y` as Latitude
   `place.geometry.location.z` as Longitude

Then it started returning it like this:

`place.geometry.location.Ya` as Latitude
   `place.geometry.location.Za` as Longitude

And today my APP wasn't working and I discovered that it was because the Google API was returning the Lat and Lon like this:

`place.geometry.location.$a` as Latitude
   `place.geometry.location.ab` as Longitude

wtf? How am I supposed to work with this? I'm thinking on simply reading the first variable inside locations as Latitude and the second as Longitude regardless their names. But I'm afraid the API might return a completely different object next time and mess up my javascript.

Anyone experienced this? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: It looks like you're touching something that's supposed to be private. That's why it's minified.

Comment: Please read the official document, and I recommend you shouldn't access internal variables. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry

Comment: In the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en , in "Place Search Results" it clearly says to tap the .location in the placeresult object for the latitude and langitude. It seems to me the problem is elsewhere, also that snippet is basically lifted from the documentation examples

Comment: I'm using `var place = autocomplete.getPlace();` to get the place info object and then `place.geometry.location` for lat and lon. Though it doesn't specify what is inside location and it seems the structure has changed (at least for me) twice in 6 months making the code look for missing variables

Comment: Because they compile the javascript code every time when they release new version of Google Maps API. I think they released twice time in this 6 month. Only official methods/properties are ensured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

place.geometry.location consists by LatLng class.
So if you want to get Latitude/Longitude, you should use like this code:

```
var lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

And the reference of the place.geometry.location is here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry