# Return address location from javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, return-value

I'm working with google map api V3 and want to get location for some address by using next function:

```
function findAddress(address) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var addrLocation = "";

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        addrLocation = "Location is: " + results[0].geometry.location;
    } else {
        addrLocation = "Not found"; }   
    });

    return addrLocation;
}
```

Then I'm trying to call findAddress function:

```
function SomeFunction(){
  alert(findAddress("New York"));
}
```

To my logic, that alert should return 'addrLocation' value, but instead it returns blank message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return a variable from Google Maps JavaScript geocoder callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also I found the same problem [retrieving lat/long of location using google.maps.geocoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807141/retrieving-lat-long-of-location-using-google-maps-geocoder). It's impossible to return value from an asynchronous call, but I can store this values in global variables for example. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not return a value from an asynchronous call, going to find a dupe since this is asked hourly.